# Script to open 12 browser windows in 12 different monitors

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, browser

Our client has a setup where a PC is connected to 12 monitors. I need a script that will open 12 different web pages, one on each monitor. The PC is running Windows 7 and any browser will do.

Comment: Is it a single Output for the 12 screens of he has 12 outputs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open browser window at specified screen / coordinates](http://superuser.com/questions/747900/open-browser-window-at-specified-screen-coordinates)

Answer (score 2):

A solution for this can be hacked together very quickly if the dimensions of each screen are known.

I would tackle it with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) using the functions [Run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm), [WinWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm), and [WinMove](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm). If you would like to maximize each window, AutoHotkey can [do that too](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMaximize.htm) :)

Comment: Suggesting that a solution should be possible is not a solution.  This does not answer the question.