# Tool to arrange browser windows on multiple monitors, interact with web page - all on startup?

Tags: linux, windows, video, multiple-monitors, automation

Imagine you wanted to arrange content for a video wall type application.  I'd like the computer to - upon startup - open a handful of browser windows, potentially interact with them (log in, drill in to a menu), arrange them across up to four monitors, and then go into a full screen mode.

The problem is somewhat similar to a kiosk or digital signage type problem, but those tend to be focused on single display.

Thanks for any input you have!

Oh while, I'm looking primarily for Windows software, if anyone is aware of solutions for linux or mac I'd love to hear those as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script to open 12 browser windows in 12 different monitors](http://superuser.com/questions/167837/script-to-open-12-browser-windows-in-12-different-monitors). In any case off-topic as a software rec question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) (cross-platform) is a very easy to use scripting language the focuses on on-screen object recognition, like clicking and moving windows. It also has an IDE the helps you capture screenshots of buttons for using in your scripts.

Otherwise for scripting you have:

- [AutoHotKey (AHK)](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (can send messages to windows, click on buttons and [do on-screen OCR](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm), like Sikuli, but doesn't have as nice of an IDE for this purpose)
- [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) (Similar to AutoIt, I personally use AHK, but mention this because it is equally popular, and similar capabilties to AHK)
- [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) (I don't have a OS X device, so I haven't used this at all, but it can be used to control applications and seems to be simple to program in)